# Adding input numbers in python, with casting included

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print the sum of numbers prompted until i press "q", i only can use while, if, elif, else and casting. Solutions??? Thanks, i tried to do total+=numero and erase the first line of my function but it gets an error that variable total its referenced before named. how can i fix that? Thanks

```
def adding_report(numero):
    numero+=numero
    total=numero
    return print(total)

while True:
thing=input("Ingrese un número o \"Q\": ")
if thing.isdigit():
    adding_report(int(thing))
elif thing.lower().startswith("q"):
    print(total)
    break
else:
    print("entrada invalida")
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `return print(total)` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tally = 0                                            # your sum

while True:

        thing = input("Ingrese un numero o \"Q\": ") # input string
        if thing.isdigit():
            num = int(thing)                             # try to make it an int

        #print( tally, "+", num, "=", tally+num)      # its an it, yehaaa
            tally += num                                 # build total sum

        else:                                          # not an int
            if (str(thing).upper() == "Q"):              # check for Q
                break                                    # we are done
            else:
                print("entrada invalida")                # typo, continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like this:

```
tally = 0                                            # your sum

while True:
    try:
        thing = input("Ingrese un numero o \"Q\": ") # input string
        num = int(thing)                             # try to make it an int

        print( tally, "+", num, "=", tally+num)      # its an it, yehaaa
        tally += num                                 # build total sum

    except:                                          # not an int
        if (str(thing).upper() == "Q"):              # check for Q
            break                                    # we are done
        else:
            print("entrada invalida")                # typo, continue

print("Total: " , tally)                             # print total
```

- You ask for a input
- You convert the input into an int

  - if the conversion is ok, you print out the sum till here
  - if the conversion is not ok, the code branches and continues at the break which tests if "Q" was inputted (your break condition for the while loop) or if
    still continue on
- outside the loop you print the final total

Comment: Thanks, thats an easy way to do it. Would be possible without try/except?

Comment: Thanks man, i switched the try/except for if and elses and it worked great.